# using space in readfile()

Tags: php, readfile, spaces

I am trying to download an xlsx file using readfile().
The filename is a string variable ($costing_url) which has spaces and is extracted from a MySQL database based on an href'd ID.

Example:

```
$costing_url="X:\Sys_Prod\WAResponse\Americas Division\2015\OMA - Mexico\ACA (vMUSE AOPS) AATC Costing 09-10-2015 ver(a).xlsx"
```

This

```
readfile($costing_url);
```

--- results in a "failed to open stream" error.

This

```
readfile("X:\Sys_Prod\WAResponse\Americas Division\2015\OMA - Mexico\ACA (vMUSE AOPS) AATC Costing 09-10-2015 ver(a).xlsx");
```

--- works just fine.

if `$costing_url` does not have any spaces in the path/filename example A works fine.

Research has indicated that the double-quotes are required to accomodate for the spaces which is what example B proves true.

My problem is that I cannot get the double-quotes escaped properly within the `readfile()`. I've tried every way I can think of but it will not translate the string `($costing_url)` when I try to quote it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried "${costing_url}" ?

Comment: There is literally no difference in how the path string is handled between the first and second examples. This leads me to believe that there is a difference in either the code, or the environment in which the code was run between the two examples. eg. different user, CLI vs SAPI, different environment, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't have anything to do with the spaces. The field in the database had a carriage return <CR> at the end of the field.

Here is a little more detail if others experience a similar issue: I trimmed the string to remove the trailing carriage return

```
$costing_url = rtrim(costing_url, "\r");
```

and also changed the readfile line to be

```
readfile((string)$costing_url);
```

Comment: What I typically do to check for this (as a quick "hex"-like editor) is use `urlencode` which will expose these characters. `var_dump(urlencode($var1)); var_dump(urlencode($var2));` In the instance of `\r` [it would've ended with `%0D`](https://eval.in/502171)

Answer (score 0):

don't use "\", use "/"

ex:
$costing_url= "X:/Sys_Prod/WAResponse/Americas Division/2015/OMA - Mexico/ACA (vMUSE AOPS) AATC Costing 09-10-2015 ver(a).xlsx"